# Class FORM-CONTROL in Bootstrap dont take effect when used in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day Bootstrap experts.

I am stuck with this problem which I can't figure out the root cause of the issue. The scenario is this. I am using bootstrap3 and incorporate it with a datatable such as this one below.

[image]

Now, when I click the "edit" link, I show a modal form which is like this. As you can see on the modal form, the SELECT OPTION is not displayed as inline block like the other two inputs.
[image]

When I debug using chrome, I found out that the class form-control adopts a width sets to auto instead it must be set as `display:inline-block`. When I unclick this, I got the desired result.
[image]

I only got this problem with the SELECT OPTION when used in DATATABLES. But for INPUTTEXT, everything is ok. I tried also to disable the CSS of datatable, but still it doesn't work. I also noticed that SELECT OPTION is ok when used in the ADD NEW RECORD option.

Any idea experts, to solve this issue? Thank you so much in advance.

**My Code:**

```
<!--START EDIT MODAL WINDOW -->
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <?php $edit_id = 'edit' . $row -> ylid ?>
   <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $edit_id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal_wrapper" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
           <?php echo form_open('csettings/edit_yrlvl/'. $row -> ylid)?>
           <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="H3">Update Grade/Year Level</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body"> 
              <div class="form-group">                                                      
                 <label>Subject Code</label>
                 <input value="<?php echo $row -> subjcode ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Subject Code" required="required" id="subjcode" name="subjcode" />
                 <input value="<?php echo $row -> subjcode ?>" type="hidden" id="hsubjcode" name="hsubjcode" />

                 <label>Description</label>
                 <input value="<?php echo $row -> subjdesc ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Subject Description" required="required" id="subjdesc" name="subjdesc" />
                 <input value="<?php echo $row -> subjdesc ?>" type="hidden" id="hsubjdesc" name="hsubjdesc" />

                 <label>Grade Level</label>
                 <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Select Grade Level</option>
                 </select>                  
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
              </div>
           </div>
           </form>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--END EDIT MODAL WINDOW -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry guys, I will close this post now as I found the answer by myself. Just to share to everyone, here is my findings:

Background:
I am using a Bootstrap v3.0 and a Datatables.

**Issue:**
When you add a **SELECT** tag in a  MODAL inside a [DATATABLE](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap), the width of that object is set to auto. Take a look at this screenshot below.
[image]

**Root cause:**
This issue is due to the fact that the DATABLE itself uses a SELECT tag in its view. Therefore, there is a conflicting use of the class **form-control**. As you see below, this SELECT tag inside a DataTable has a width set to AUTO. Since I am using a datatable, then anything pass to it inside this table will inherit whatever attributes set to the class. In this case, the SELECT tag.
[image]

**Solution:**
This is my first solution:
I create a `custom.css` where I override the value of this class FORM-CONTROL.

```
.form-inline select.form-control{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

With this code which I override the class, I got the desired result for my MODAL such as this one. The width of the object SELECT tag is now set to 100% unlike before it is set to auto.
[image]

However, using the overriding method has an effect to the DataTable itself. As you can see below, the 
Label of the Navigation now is aligned below the options since it uses a width property of 100%. This is what I am saying that there is a conflicting property of the SELECT tag when used inside a DATATABLE.
[image]

So my **PERMANENT** solution with this issue, is to create a new class copying the whole property of the FORM-CONTROL class then assign it to the SELECT tag within the MODAL inside the DataTable. Declare this as **INTERNAL** type of CSS declaration..

```
.select-option{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 34px;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            font size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.428571429;
            color:#555;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-color:#fff;
            background-image:none;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius:4px;
            box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
            transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        }
```

Now with this new class, I assigned this to the SELECT tag rather than using the FORM-CONTROL class.

```
<select class="select-option" name="ylcode" id="ylcode">
```

So the result is now what I expected. The label on the SELECT tag in the DataTable is now aligned correctly as seen below.
[image]

And on the MODAL view, the SELECT tag has a width now set to 100% and it is correctly aligned with the other objects.

[image]

I hope I have shared a little bit knowledge to this community. Thank you so much.